# Iptv ub310-dvbt driver for ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, dvb

I have digital usb tv tuner `iptv ub310-dvbt`. How can i connect this device to Ubuntu 12.04?
This device not listed in [LinuxTV](http://linuxtv.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you also searched on the usb ids? Use `lsusb` to list the usb devices. It isn't uncommon, especially with DVB tuners, to resell the same device under different names.